# Add to cart button redirect to empty cart page

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.9 edition and building eCommerce website.

My product belongs to simple product type, which has many attributes like color, size, style, occasion and many more and in category page all the attributes shows as it is its work fine but there is one problem coming is that when i click on add to cart button it redirects to empty cart page that there is nothing selected product in shopping basket.

Comment: Turn on your logging: 
Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes
And check message from error.log

Answer (score 0):

For me, there's nothing in the error/exception log. When I try to use the "Add to Cart" button or the "Add to Compare" link on the home page OR the product page, the only message is produced in the system log:

```
ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in .../includes/src/__default.php on line 24251
ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in .../includes/src/__default.php on line 24253
```

This is the code that's referred to in the notice:

```
public function getEventConfig($area, $eventName)
{
    //return $this->getNode($area)->events->{$eventName};
    if (!isset($this->_eventAreas[$area])) {
        this->_eventAreas[$area] = $this->getNode($area)->events;
    }
    return $this->_eventAreas[$area]->{$eventName};
}
```

this -> and return $this -> are lines 24251 and 24253

I'm using Magento 1.9 CE in a multi-store environment. I get the same response in IE, Chrome & Firefox and with Default or any other template.

It doesn't seem like this is the problem, though, because I get the same notice/log entry whether I add to cart or compare from the home page or the product page. The actions work from the product page. They don't work on the home page in any scenario.

I've looked at cookies--they're being set. Sessions are being maintained. The console in Firebug shows no script errors.

So I'm really at a loss here.

The code that does not work (home page) is:

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('.../checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93dGZvY2tlci5uZXQv/product/7125/form_key/VbcZK5UdJk7IifcW/')">
```

The code that does work (product page) is:

```
<form action=".../checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93dGZvY2tlci5uZXQvbnd0LXB1bWEteW91dGgtbHMtc29jY2VyLXBsYXllci1wdWxsb3Zlci1qNC0wMTEyODMxLWNpcmNhLTE5OTAtcy1yb3lhbC14bC5odG1sP19fX1NJRD1V/product/7125/form_key/DHocBeqxeGRmuboN/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form">
```

So a couple of things?

It's like direct interaction with the cart works; AJAX does not.

There's apparently also some variable that's tacked on to the location once you get to the checkout/cart/add form on the product page.

Both locations start with the same string: aHR0cHM6Ly93dGZvY2tlci5uZXQ The product page version that works has some other string appended to it.

Thank you to anyone who has some advice on this!